# Right alignment without resizing parent

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to align something to the right without resizing it's parent. So technically the box size should be dependent on the text object, and the icon should be aligned to the right.

```
return new Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      new Text("this is a test string"),
      new Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: new Icon(Icons.speaker_notes),
      ),
    ]);
```

Once the alignment is set to Alignment.topRight the box gets drawn with the full screen width. I understand why it gets rendered like this, but can't think of a solution either. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text("this is a test string"),
                new Icon(Icons.speaker_notes),
              ]),
        ),
      );
    }
```

**Result**

[image]